# Binary classification of every time series step based on past and future values

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series, classification

I'm currently facing a Machine Learning problem and I've reached a point where I need some help to proceed.

I have various time series of positional (`x`, `y`, `z`) data tracked by sensors. I've developed some more features. For example, I rasterized the whole 3D space and calculated a `cell_x`, `cell_y` and `cell_z` for every time step. The time series itself have variable lengths.

My goal is to build a model which classifies every time step with the labels `0` or `1` (binary classification based on past and future values). Therefore I have a lot of training time series where the labels are already set.

One thing which could be very problematic is that there are very few `1`'s labels in the data (for example only 3 of 800 samples are labeled with `1`).

It would be great if someone can help me in the right direction because there are too many possible problems:

- Wrong hyperparameters
- Incorrect model
- Too few `1`'s labels, but I think that's not a big problem because I only need the model to suggests the right time steps. So I would only use the peaks of the output.
- Bad or too less training data
- Bad features

I appreciate any help and tips.

Answer (score 1):

Your model seems very strange. Why only use 2 units in lstm layer? Also your problem is a binary classification. In this case you should choose only one neuron in your output layer (try to insert one additional dense layer between and lstm layer and try dropout layers between them).

Binary crossentropy does not make much sense with 2 output neurons, if you don't have a multi label problem. But if you're switching to one output neuron it's the right one. You also need sigmoid then as activation function.

As last advice: Try class weights. 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html
This can make a huge difference, if you're label are unbalanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the model using tensorflow BasicLSTMCell, the shape of your data fits for BasicLSTMCell in TensorFlow [you can find Documentation for BasicLSTMCell here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicLSTMCell) and for creating the model [this Documentation contain code that will help to build BasicLstmCell model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent) . Hope this will help you, Cheers.